# Call c# executable in c++ managed and run asynchronously

Tags: c#, c++, startprocessinfo

I would like to run c# executable file abc.exe at the end of c++ managed project main functionality. abc.exe needs to run asynchronously without disturbing the c++ managed project even it encounter any errors.

I have found that process run .exe async but what if .exe encounter any error will that exe c++ managed project?

```
        Process ^p;
        ProcessStartInfo ^pInfo;

        pInfo = gcnew ProcessStartInfo();
        pInfo->Verb = "open";
        pInfo->FileName = "d:\\abc.exe";
        pInfo->UseShellExecute = true;

        p = Process::Start(pInfo);
```

Answer (score 2):

> abc.exe needs to run asynchronously without disturbing the c++ managed project even it encounter any errors.

Two separate processes will normally not affect each other without explicitly writing code to communicate between each other. If both processes use a shared resource, like hardware or a file, then they can interfere with each other through that shared resource. We would need more details on your C# and C++ projects to tell you whether they *can* affect each other in that way.

> I have found that process run .exe async but what if .exe encounter any error will that exe c++ managed project?

The `abc.exe` process will exit and the C++ process will continue to run as if nothing happened. You may implement code to wait for `abc.exe` to exit and handle its return value if you wish.

---

By design, all processes are meant to run asynchronously with their own independent memory. This is how `Explorer.exe` can be used to launch programs but does not crash when a program it launched crashes.